# If a series is absolutely convergent, then does it have to pass the ratio test or the root test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

That being said. I learned in the lecture, that if a series passes the ratio test and/or the root test, then it has to converge absolutely.

Is the reversal also true, that a series will pass the ratio test and/or the root test if it converges absolutely.

Comment: No. Look at $\sum 1/n^2$, for example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test: “if L = 1 or the limit fails to exist, then the test is inconclusive, because there exist both convergent and divergent series that satisfy this case.”

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test: “... otherwise the test is inconclusive (the series may diverge, converge absolutely or converge conditionally).”

Comment: Thanks that answered my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Every series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^\alpha$, with $\alpha<-1$, is absolutely convergent. But both the ratio test and the root test are inconclusive when applied to it.